# localization for WSO2 CEP product

Tags: localization, wso2, wso2-cep

I try to localize WSO2 CEP product.

I found some post regard with 
http://tanyamadurapperuma.blogspot.kr/2013/10/localizing-wso2-carbon-products-part-1.html

So i changed all JSResources.properties and Resources.properties files to JSResources_kr.properties and Resources_kr.properties.

**But all character are broken.**

Comment: Could you please post a sample of what's in your .properties files and an example of what the broken characters look like?  thanks!

Comment: in the org.wso2.carbon.i18n_4.2.0.jar file...i changed JSResources.properties --> JSResources_ko.properties and Resources.properties --> Resources_ko.properties. In Resources_ko.properties file, i changes some english to korean...like ### Menu Definitions ###
component.help=도움
component.home=홈
component.monitor=모니터
component.manage=관리
component.configure=설정
component.registry=등록
component.governance.registry=자원
component.tools=툴
manage.security=보안
<br>
but all the korean are broken in the view......

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this and was able to see broken Korean characters. (Please see the screenshot)

[image]

I have already created a public JIRA [1] for this issue and fix might be available in one of the upcoming releases.

Thanks,

Upul

[1]. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-15893